# How to configure open dns?

Tags: internet, opendns

how can I configure it so that I would not need to change the settings after a computer restart? I really wanted to block the sites that are useless. 
By the way I chose the setting for a computer, not the router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to your IP settings changing upon reboot, install the [OpenDNS Updater](http://www.opendns.com/support/dynamic_ip_downloads). It will update OpenDNS on your new IP settings whenever they change.

Comment: tnx for your help man,

Comment: You're most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

A little more info would help (OS, version?), but in general:

- Open up the network configuration program/control panel
- Find the configuration page for TCP/IP
- If it is currently set to get the DNS server from a DHCP, change the setting so you can set it yourself
- Set the values for DNS server to: 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220

Or just install the updater that John T mentioned :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice OpenDNS tutorial for you:

**[Using OpenDNS for adult site filtering and online safety](http://www.top-windows-tutorials.com/OpenDNS.html)**

including a [video](http://www.top-windows-tutorials.com/Block-adult-websites.html) that explains how to use the OpenDNS Updater and Dashboard.

*If you're using Windows 7, refer to the Windows Vista section.*